# Puppet-lint warning when iterating over nested hash in puppet manifest

Tags: puppet

I am iterating over a hash of arrays in one of my puppet manifests

```
 1 # class to manage needed packages
 2 class profile::packages (
 3 ){
 4   $packages = hiera_hash('profile::packages::managed', {})
 5 
 6   if $packages != {} {
 7     $packages.each | String $package_state, Array $packages_array | {
 8       $packages_array.each | Integer $idx, String $package | {
 9         notify { "${package} with ${idx} should be ${package_state}": }
10       }
11     }
12   }
13 }
```

but I get a puppet-lint warning.

> WARNING: top-scope variable being used without an explicit namespace
>   on line 8 
>   Blockquote
>   WARNING: top-scope variable being used without an explicit
>   namespace on line 9

The code is running well, so it's a question of puppet-lint. Maybe there is a way to configure puppet-lint to recognize variables in the lambda blocks?

Comment: puppet-lint tips added [here](http://puppet-lint.com/checks/variable_scope/) can disable the whole scope checking but this is not want in this context.

Comment: This code can be improved with refactoring to also not throw the lint warnings.

Comment: So let us know i we can refactor the code to remove the lint warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [a known issue](https://github.com/rodjek/puppet-lint/issues/549) in puppet-lint at the time of writing. It has limited support for Puppet 4 language features.